# accessing files named in an array

Tags: php, file

I am a new PHP developer and I just started working with files in PHP.
I have the following code to count number of txt files in the directory and store their names in an array and then using a loop display the total lines in each of the files!
here is the code, help me where I have gone wrong!

```
$dir = opendir('directory/');
$num_files = 0;
$dir_files[] = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))){
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..','Thumbs.db')) and !is_dir($file)){
    $num_files++;
    echo $file;
    array_push($dir_files,$file);
    echo "<br />";
    }
}

echo "--------------------------------------<br />";
echo "Number of files in this directory: ".$num_files."<br />";
echo "--------------------------------------<br />";
foreach($dir_files as $dir_file=>$value){
    $file='directory/'.$value;
    $linecount = 0;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
      $line = fgets($handle);
      $linecount++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "File $file has $linecount lines!";
}
```

I get the following errors:

Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_practice\read_lines_of_files.php on line 19

Warning: fopen(directory/Array): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_practice\read_lines_of_files.php on line 21

Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_practice\read_lines_of_files.php on line 22

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: What part of the script fails?

Comment: $value is an array, so chech what you get with print_r($dir_files);

Comment: print_r($dir_files) result: Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => file1.txt [2] => file2.txt )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
$dir_files[] = array();
```

to

```
$dir_files = array();
```

And:
[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a file pointer resource on success, or `FALSE` on error.As it is throwing an error opening the file, feof() is receiving FALSE instead of a file pointer resource: so you get the error `"expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"...`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is toooooooo lengthy. Try this : This will do whole functionality for you, let me know if any issues.

```
foreach(glob('directory/*.txt',GLOB_BRACE) as $value){
    $file      =$value;
    $linecount = 0;
    $handle    = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
      $line    = fgets($handle);
      $linecount++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "File $file has $linecount lines!";
}
```

Comment: Ohh, this is perfect Prasanth; Thank you